# Keras validation with fit_generator and dropout layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I hope someone can help me answer a question about Keras dropout layers in combination with a fit_generator.

Currently I am training a model containing multiple dropout layers. I understood however that when predicting with a model containing dropout layers, Keras will automatically disable them by utilizing a learning phase variable.

I wonder if this also applied to training and validating with a fit_generator. Where upon validating with a generator (validation_data) the dropout layers will be deactivated?